# npm install a package that is locally on my system

Tags: node.js, npm-install, google-chrome-headless, puppeteer

When I want to install puppeteer it stops with error

```
ERROR: Failed to download Chromium r499413! Set  "PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD" env variable to skip download.
Error: Download failed: server returned code 403. URL: https://storage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/Linux_x64/499413 /chrome-linux.zip
```

, So I download the chrome-linux.zip from 
URL: https://storage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/Linux_x64/499413/chrome-linux.zip manually.

Now, how should I say to npm that the package is locally on my system and it can install it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

see the [Puppeteer Environment Variable](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#environment-variables), it's related to skip automatic downloading chromium.

So to launch puppeteer, you are able to specify `executablePath` via [puppeteer.launch](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#puppeteerlaunchoptions).

```
const browser= await puppeteer.launch({
  executablePath: 'path/to/your/cromium'
});
```